# Pérdida de puntos por usuario eliminado

Tags: discusión, reputación, eliminación-de-usuarios

Pues me ha pasado estas fiestas que no he entrado a SOes casi en ningún momento. Hoy he vuelto al trabajo y miro la web de SOes y veo que he perdido 160 puntos. Resulta que un usuario a quien yo respondí bastantes preguntas fue eliminado. Me pregunto y al mismo tiempo propondría que si un usuario es eliminado no perdamos los puntos. ¿Porque qué culpa tenemos de que ese usuario haya sido eliminado por sus malas practicas?

Comment: Nos sucedió a muchos, en rangos similares al tuyo. Supuestamente, como se describe en [What does “user was removed” mean and why did my reputation change because of it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126470/304899), ocurre porque se elimina un usuario... Sin embargo, en [Don't throw away all votes when a user is deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268608/304899) se mencionan límites según la cantidad de votos emitidos y la reputación del usuario, pero no se detalla el límite. En el caso que mencionas, sólo podríamos esperar que aplique el primero (no tenía una rep alta)...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Como muy bien explican en la publicación [Don't throw away all votes when a user is deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268608/346154) ya existen mecanismos que previenen la pérdida de la reputación causada por la pérdida de los votos de un usuario eliminado. En concreto:

Hay 2 umbrales:

- Cantidad de votos realizados por el usuario
- Cantidad de usuarios afectados *significativamente* por los votos.

Desconozco (y se desconocen de manera intencionada) el umbral en sí pero por lo que he investigado y preguntado sí son adaptados a cada sitio y son bastante bajos.

Si **cualquiera** de esos 2 umbrales es sobrepasado la eliminación del usuario se detiene hasta que alguien la revisa. Si no se llega a esos umbrales la eliminación sigue adelante y los votos se pierden.

Para el caso concreto del usuario que estamos hablando, **SÍ** que se llegó a esos umbrales por lo que el proceso se paralizó para su análisis. El problema es que existe una tercera cosa a tener en cuenta:

- Si durante la revisión de la eliminación de un usuario (solo si se ha llegado a uno de los dos umbrales) se ve que el usuario ha sido partícipe de algún tipo de anormalidad con los votos (voto serial, votos dirigidos, etc... ) **se eliminan los votos igualmente.**
- En caso contrario, **los votos se mantienen** y se traspasan al usuario Community.

Para el usuario en concreto, hubo *bastantes* irregularidades en ese sentido (varios votos dirigidos y también voto serial) por lo que al hacerse la revisión se descartaron sus votos.

He preguntado y escalado un poco para asegurarme de lo que he explicado y efectivamente esta es la respuesta oficial:

> We don't preserve votes in cases where there is a past history of voting abuse of any kind.

Que significa que si hay alguna irregularidad con los votos (como así ha sido) se pierden todos los votos.

Comment: me parece bien, sobre todo si se comprobó que cometió algún tipo de abuso, tenemos que evitar a toda costa las marionetas y los votantes seriales pues resta mucho a la calidad del sitio.