# El robo de puntos llegó a soes

Tags: discusión

De manera totalmente descarada se hace presente la sobrepticia práctica del robo de puntos tan famosa en soen, me dí cuenta de ello hace poco cuando ví que mis puntos bajaron y me quedé así:

[image: sorpresa nivel Dany Trejo xD]

y al revisar la pregunta pude ver que había otra respuesta aceptada que aparentemente había sido puesta en el exacto momento que yo puse la mía...

[image: molto concidenci xD]

[image: al mismo tiempo?]

Esto era raro y necesitaba investigar ese misterio....
Así que simplemente fui a las [revisiones de esa pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/408805/revisions) y me hallé una sorpresa muy sorpresosa:

[image: con las manos en la masa, Jorgesys haciendo trampa]

[image: ni me sorprende]

Y eso se parece más a lo que recuerdo, alguien respondiendo por responder y a mí conteniéndome de ponerle el "Te he votado negativo porque tu respuesta es totalmente incorrecta".

Obviamente el OP siendo novato al abrir su pregunta y ver una nueva respuesta más corta decidió cambiar la respuesta aceptada de la mía a la de este avaricioso<sup>1</sup> usuario, a pesar de que sus modificaciones dejaban su código exactamente igual que el mío.

[image: yo bien sorprendido alv! xD]

Sinceramente he apoyado a <strike>SOez</strike>SOEs desde que estaba en la beta y he seguido con ánimos a pesar de las amargas opiniones de mi amigo Luiggi Mendoza Jarahuanco quien decidió eliminar su cuenta de SOEs (ya sé F, adiós amigo, que la fuerza te acompañe).

¿Qué deberíamos de hacer en estos casos? ¿Simplemente aceptar que la vida es injusta? ¿Cambiarme mi nombre a "Jorgesys deja de dañar"?

Gracias por leerme :3

[image: bytes :'v]

### Notas

<sup>1</sup> agregar los adjetivos locales del español de tu localidad de tu preferencia

<sup>2</sup> Si no le entendés a los memes necesitas ver más el canal de `te lo resumo así nomás` en youtube

Comment: ¿No existe un emoji de aplausos en SOes? Porque te pondría miles.

Comment: En los comentarios creo que no se puede, en github normalmente los pongo así: https://gist.github.com/rxaviers/7360908

Comment: Poder,lo que se dice poder, se  puede 

Comment: Pues esto:  * `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`.

Comment: Si se concede el beneficio de la duda, invitando a aclarar, cabe el 

Comment: Perdón, quizás no estoy entendiendo, quizás yo necesito un "te lo resumo" para tu publicación :-) ... Por un lado, estás asumiendo que robó tu código, sin dar el beneficio de la duda de que quizás se dio cuenta solo y lo mejoró sin siquiera leer tu respuesta (convengamos que el código tampoco es nada del otro mundo, es una sola línea y bastante genérica, y la línea no está *exactamente* igual)... Y por otro lado hablás de "robar puntos", pero ¿qué culpa tiene si el autor de la pregunta es un idiota? -eso sí podría haberte contestado al comentario o acá. No me gusta que no lo haya hecho

Comment: @Pollo démosle la oportunidad a que el usuario en cuestión se explique, ya que es moderador y alguna razón tendrá, aunque es el usuario con más polémicas generadas en meta.

Comment: Concuerdo con Pollo: en el peor de los casos se podría considerar plagio. Tampoco hay que dejar que puntos y medallas ocupen espacio en nuestras mentes y vidas.

Comment: Hola Ruslan López, **si asumes "robo de código" creo que el código que veo presentas existe en internet. Si asumes "robo de puntos"  yo simplemente corregí mi respuesta para no dejar información incorrecta y no me puedo asignar los votos a mí, eso lo realiza el OP, tal vez desconoces esto.** Desgraciadamente no puedo reportar tu publicación como "irrespetuoso o abusivo" hacía mí ya que la cerraría.

Comment: @Jorgesys Totalmente de acuerdo en que no hay "robo de puntos" en mejorar una respuesta y el resto es la acción del autor. Sin embargo, me da la impresión de que no estás respondiendo puntualmente a lo que se publicó. Al decir que el código existe en internet, no estás afirmando ni negando haber copiado de otra respuesta sin referenciar debidamente. Además, me preocupa un poco que consideres irrespetuosa o abusiva a una publicación de este estilo: afirma algo que ni a vos ni a nadie le gustaría leer sobre su persona, de acuerdo, pero en ningún lugar veo que te esté faltando el respeto.

Comment: Aclaro algo aca que me vienen preguntando. Considero el tono y la forma de la publicacion abusiva y de mal gusto. Se puede preguntar que paso sin hacerlo tan agresivo. Entiendo que se intento un tono humoristico a la presentacion, pero de esta forma, se acerca mucho a que sea insultiva. Se podria haber pedido de buena forma la linea de tiempo y se podria haber preguntado, de mucha mejor forma, que paso.

Comment: @gbianchi En SO no existe el concepto de tono(salvo que publiquen un video o un audio) ya que esta asociado a la entonación de una persona, y esa entonación es de cada lector(por ejemplo cuando tu lo lees entonces tu le das esa entonación). En SO se recomienda que no darle ningun tipo de entonación( o darle una entonación de buena fe) para evitar este tipo de problemas. La publicación puede ser irónica pero no es abusiva(como la acción de bloquear que sí lo fue), quizas de mal gusto dependiendo de la persona

Comment: @eyllanesc por eso mismo digo. A mi el tono de esta publicacion (las comunicaciones tienen un tono mas alla de los sonidos) me parece abusivo, porque expresa de una forma poco amigable un problema particular. Entonces siento que se esta abusando en la forma de referirse a otra persona (porque mas alla de todo, somos personas) y mas, a una persona que no se conoce y no se sabe como puede tomar esta forma de referirse. Por lo unico que no cierro esta publicacion, es porque pareceria un abuso. Pero yo tambien opino que viola "be nice"

Comment: @gbianchi Yo pienso que es sarcástico, y no es un abuso hacerlo de esa forma. No creo que deba ser amigable sino respetuoso en un post que refleja que han abusado del sistema. El moderador a que se refiere continuamente abusa de su poder(por ejemplo https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3900, https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4787) y nunca responde ante esos abusos sino que distrae con otro tipo de comentarios, ni los otros moderadores (que por transparencia) deberian dar su posición ante esas acciones.

Comment: @eyllanesc esto excede al rol de moderador. Que posicion se supone que uno deberia tener? yo por lo pronto no voy a responder a una publicacion sarcastica y que no me gusta. Las explicaciones, las tendra que dar la persona involucrada en esto. Yo puedo mostrar el timeline, y no hay nada incorrecto en ello. Es mas, ahora la publicacion tiene como respuesta correcta la otra, supongo que por el efecto meta. Respuestas copiadas, duplicadas, con mismo codigo, hay montones, y en ninguna suponemos mala fe.

Comment: @gbianchi  Yo no me refiero a este post ya que la explicación es trivial: El OP confunde robo con un conjunto de acciones que no puede probar,yendo por la buena fe el moderador diamantado edito su pregunta con un codigo similar al otro usuario, con la de mala fe el moderador diamantado se dio cuenta que su respuesta fue incorrecta por lo que copip la respuesta del otro usuario, y yendo por el principio de buena fe entonces se elige la primera opción

Comment: @gbianchi Yo me refiero al conflictos de intereses, a la forma de como debe actuar un moderador diamantado en dar explicaciones claras y calmar la situación. Los moderadores diamantados son como jueces donde se espera que provean transparencia y calma en las discusiones, y no echarle más polvora. Ademas tambien me refiero a los otros post que te señale donde claramente el OP nunca da una explicación de sus errores sino que deja pasar el tiempo

Comment: @gbianchi Es mejor sanjar el problema explicando claramente lo que paso en vez de seguir no respondiendo a nada e irse por los lados. ¿Que acción pueden tomar los moderadores si otro moderador no tiene acciones de buena fe o se reusa a responder? Nos quedamos todos "callados" y que siga el abuso. El usuario Jorgesys(para mi ya no moderador) deberia dar un paso al costado ya que parece que no sabe manejar esos problemas que suelen suceder(y van a seguir sucediendo)

Comment: @eyllanesc coincido contigo en este último comentario. Sin ánimos de desacreditar el trabajo de los moderadores. Una persona que por alguna razón haya perdido la confianza de usuarios que regularmente colaboran en el sitio (caso de Ruslan, por ejemplo) tal vez debería plantearse su propia situación. Hoy es Ruslan, antes fueron otros, que han incluso tomado la drástica decisión de cerrar su cuenta. Tal vez, sólo tal vez, cabe la posibilidad de que el aludido reflexione, cambie o se retire. De lo contrario, tal como afirmas, esto ocurrirá nuevamente, y no es la imagen que debe tener [es.so].

Comment: Interesante post. Si bien llevo cerca de 4 años acá jamás me ha tocado tal robo de puntos copiando una repuesta mía (me ha pasado lo típico donde algun colega responde de mejor manera y al OP le convence más, cosa que aplaudo); lo que me preocupa acá es que se esté culpando a un usuario tan respetado como @Jorgesys. En caso que sea cierto lo que levantan Ruslan, quien también es un colega muy respetado, es para tirar un poco las orejas y darnos cuenta que este foro es para ayudarnos entre todos y no caer en la banalidad de robar puntos por el mero hecho de tener más reputación.

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera Mis comentarios no son sobre el *robo de puntos* sino por la forma de como maneja problemas similares el usuario Jorgesys.

Comment: ¿Qué tiene que ver Luiggi en todo esto?

Comment: Me sorprende y apena lo que ha ocurrido. Tanto Ruslan como Jorge son usuarios importantes de esta comunidad, me he cruzado con ambos en algunas preguntas/respuestas y creo que lo  que ha habido aquí ha sido un mal entendido. Leo aquí mismo algunos comentarios sobre Jorge que me entristecen y espero que no sean ciertos (uno puede cambiar con el tiempo o se le puede ir la autoridad a la cabeza) espero que no sea así y si es así se puede rectificar. SOes es de gran  ayuda para mucha gente, en el pasado yo tuve diferencias personales con algunos, planteándome incluso abandonar esta comunidad ...

Comment: Yo desde siempre he pensado que JorgeSys es un usuario excelente, que ayuda y acoge muchísimo a los usuarios (solo hay que ver [su actividad](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/95/jorgesys?tab=activity), incansable). También, que debería ejercer con más transparencia la moderación. Ya son unas cuantas veces que aquí en Meta podría haber dicho "oye pues hubo una confusión" o "es que pensé que X" y todos habríamos quedado tranquilos. Rehuir el debate no hace ningún bien y hace normal la pérdida de confianza. Estamos aún a tiempo, @Jorge.

Comment: ... pero me quedé, gracias a comentarios de varios de uds., y no me arrepiento. En el pasado hacía comparaciones de SOes con su homólogo inglés (las preguntas respuestas en inglés me parecían geniales y de hecho lo son, las nuestras más pobres), pero mi experiencia de aquel sitio (SO en inglés) es que ha perdido mucho en "humanidad". Lo digo por experiencia propia: he planteado preguntas en situaciones de bloqueo con mi código y he sido ignorado o pregunta cerrada. Hoy día SOes aporta humanidad y buenas preguntas/respuestas, depende de nosotros que siga así. Arreglemos esto de buenas maneras.

Comment: @A.Cedano puede que JorgeSys sea un excelente usuario, pero una cosa muy diferente es la moderación, de todos los moderadores que hay, el es el que mas revuelo causa, por el simple hecho de no responder ante sus actos, hay varios ejemplos aquí en meta, a mi personalmente no me inspira confianza ya que es un moderador que parece por encima de todo y que no da explicaciones de sus actos y rehuye del problema, parece que no acepta sus errores, con una sencilla explicación o disculpa este post hubiese sido menos revoltoso, pero optó por un abuso de poder y ahora hay dos

Answer (score 11):

Con respecto a la situación que expones como “robo de puntos” y que comentas es “tan famosa”.

**Te ofrezco una sincera disculpa si crees que mi intención fue como comentas el  robar puntos, te aseguro que no fue mi intención, simplemente realice mi publicación, cuando  me dí cuenta del error y lo corregí, es algo que comúnmente realizo.**

Te comento que únicamente el OP tiene la decisión de aceptar una respuesta como aceptada, el usuario que responde no puede realizar esta acción. Si el OP selecciona otra respuesta como la acertada , es su decisión personal.

Como experiencia  te comento que en el sitio, al igual que a varios usuarios, puede suceder que pierdas puntos por diversas situaciones. ya sea por [voto serial negativo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/663/qu%c3%a9-es-el-voto-serial-y-c%c3%b3mo-me-afecta), porque [el usuario al que respondiste  fue eliminado](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1308/p%c3%a9rdida-de-puntos-por-usuario-eliminado) , porque el OP decide aceptar otra respuesta, e incluso el OP decide agregar su propia respuesta y asignarla como la aceptada.

Podemos ver en ocasiones que la respuesta aceptada es solo un enlace, no tiene una explicación correcta, infinidad de detalles que no cumplen con lo dictado en el [Centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), incluso si tienes suficiente experiencia puedes determinar que es una respuesta incorrecta la cual fue aceptada y aún puntuada positivamente cuando en cambio tu respuesta sabes fehacientemente que debería ser la correcta.

Con respecto a editar tu respuesta, si te equivocas en una respuesta, y conoces que hay un error ya sea porque un usuario te alerto o porque tu mismo sabes que es incorrecta lo que debemos realizar es corregir la información para evitar que algún usuario pueda tomar información incorrecta en el sitio, realizar esta acción no está prohibida, sin embargo es de beneficio para la comunidad.

**Espero no tengas la idea de que si un usuario responde la misma pregunta ya no debe editar su publicación para que te “robe puntos”, más aún si la respuesta tiene errores y debería ser corregida.** En ocasiones personalmente no tengo tiempo de ver otras publicaciones ni pasa por mi mente lo que indicas como "robo de puntos".

Siempre he notado que algunos usuarios se esfuerzan por realizar respuestas muy documentadas y con contenido que seguramente ayudará a otros usuarios, pero no son las respuestas aceptadas, sin embargo seguramente estas respuestas serán de gran ayuda para los usuarios de la comunidad actuales y futuros, lo cual es uno de los objetivos principales del sitio.

[image: SOes cucho cogi1]

**Al final es decisión personal del usuario que realizó la pregunta determinar qué respuesta es la que considera como aceptada, nunca de los demás usuarios.**

Como experiencia personal te puedo comentar que simplemente hay que esforzarnos en nuestras posibilidades por realizar buenas respuestas y demasiado importante evitar la frustración, en algún momento estas buenas respuestas son recompensadas por la comunidad.

---

---

Con respecto a el adjetivo que realizas hacía mi, “avaricioso usuario”, lo cual considero personalmente irrespetuoso , si te refieres a mi reputación:

[image: repu Jorgesys Elenasys]

Es la reputación que he obtenido participando en el sitio, no soy el mejor, simplemente trato de participar continuamente en el sitio, te puedo asegurar que no la he conseguido fácilmente, esto sin tratar de “robar puntos” a otros usuarios u obtener reputación de forma inapropiada. **Me gustaría tener más tiempo para participar en el sitio, sin embargo tengo otras actividades personales que definitivamente son muy importantes.**

Si perdiste algunos puntos y esto es preocupante, te expongo el caso de un usuario:

- Tiene el mayor número de votos negativos en el sitio.
- Tiene el mayor número respuestas con de votos negativos que al final se convirtieron en respuesta aceptada.
- Tiene el mayor número de votos negativos por parte de un único usuario.

¿Muy preocupante verdad?. El objetivo del sitio no es obtener puntos, es ayudar, compartir conocimiento y pasarla bien.

Te comparto que en algún momento para mí y seguramente para otros usuario fue frustrante tener publicaciones votadas negativamente las cuales realizaba con empeño y me preguntaba qué parte era la que algún usuario determinó que no era correcta mi respuesta, aún más frustrante ver publicaciones que pudieran ser comentarios los cuales eran votados positiva-mente, en este caso un usuario novel al ver mi respuesta puntuada negativamente en ocasiones tomaba otra respuesta como la aceptada, pero los retos son buenos y aquí continuó aportando.

[image: SOes cucho cogi neg]

**Evita pensar en el solo objetivo de obtener reputación, trata de compartir tu conocimiento y diviértete en el sitio.**

También al igual tu y varios usuarios he apoyado al sitio desde su versión beta y su posterior liberación y no únicamente me enfoco en responder preguntas, además de responder preguntas en el sitio, también tengo participación:

- [Votando.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all)
- [Editando](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Editors&filter=all)
- [Moderando](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators)

(por cierto, alguna vez se comentó que por responder preguntas en el sitio, no enfocaba mi esfuerzo en realizar tareas de moderación, puedo asegurar que de acuerdo a mis estadísticas no estoy debajo del promedio de tareas de moderación.)

---

---

El usuario que comentas lo recuerdo, con amplio conocimiento de Java :-), de hecho algunas de sus publicaciones tanto aquí como en el sitio en inglés han sido para mí de mucha ayuda. Por cierto, recuerdo que aún siendo un moderador fue señalado en varias ocasiones (algunas personalmente creo que de forma injusta), pero no entiendo que tengo que ver yo con su decisión de eliminar su cuenta en este sitio ¿?.

---

---

Finalmente el OP ya [te asignó ahora la respuesta como aceptada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/408777/el-contenido-de-un-jtextarea-no-se-guarda-en-un-archivo-y-aun-por-encima-me-da-e/408805#408805), además recibiste una gran cantidad de votos positivos y ahora es tu [publicación con más votos en toda tu estancia en el sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/342/ruslan-l%c3%b3pez?tab=answers&sort=votes).

En cambio mi publicación recibió votos negativos, de cualquier forma trataré de responder con exactitud desde el inicio.

Comment: Excelente respuesta, Jorge, gracias por ella.

Comment: Es un paso importante para subsanar, corregir y aclarar. Ojalá esto sea todo, tu aclaración aceptada y la comunidad enriquecida. Sé que muchos (yo incluido) esperaba una reacción de tu parte. Y aunque se podría decir que debió ser inmediata, también cabe el *más vale tarde que nunca*. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Entiendo que quisieras imitar el tono "humoristico" de la pregunta usando memes pero en la pregunta parece que son reacciones del usuario que la escribe y en tu respuesta, los memes de los perros, **parece** un poco de burla hacia Ruslan. Igual estoy malinterpreando esas dos imagenes. Un saludo

Comment: Mil gracias por responder Jorgesys. Hay realmente un abismo de diferencia al poder leer tu punto de vista. Personalmente, creo que no era necesario que indiques qué es lo que hacés en/para el sitio, que nunca estuvo en tela de juicio, y que si lo sentiste necesario es también para evaluar los tonos y las acciones de todos los que participaron (me incluyo).

Comment: Buena respuesta Jorge. Sobre todo, creo que el punto está en entender todos que ganar puntos aquí no vale de nada. Es el hecho de poder ayudar a compañeros que necesitan a alguien que revise su código o que les dé una pista para seguir con su trabajo lo que nos entretetiene y realmente nos da alegría/ilusión de participar aquí. Ánimo a todos y construyamos un SOe mejor!!!

Answer (score 8):

a todos, creo que sin querer nos hemos tomado muy personal todo esto, y eso era lo que quería evitar, por eso puse memes para que pasaran un buen rato y no un mal rato como yo en ese momento.

Me autoresponderé de manera concisa y agradezco sus aportes en los comentarios esperando que esto sirva de referencia y ayuda a alguien que pase por esto.

---

Estos temas si bien son difíciles deben de ser tratados con la importancia y delicadez que merecen, evitando siempre ofenderse.

En retrospectiva puedo decir que la mejor desición que pude haber tomado fue **acudir a la comunidad**, pues siempre ayudarán en su mayoría a aclarar malentendidos.

No todos tienen malas intenciones, algunos estamos pasando por un mal momento o estamos lidiando con más de lo que creemos poder manejar en el momento, y eso nos hace susceptibles a equivocaciones y comportamientos desagradables y que entristezcan a los demás, esta vez no hablo de Jorgesys, hablo de mí... estaba pasando un momento muy obscuro de mi vida a causa de un problema de manejo de emociones, aquellos que directamente o indirectamente hayan lidiado con Borderline o TLP como le llaman( si no basta con que imagines lo que es un infierno personal que te afecta a tí y a todos los que llegues a querer ), realmente entenderán que traté de mesurarme en mi percepción de lo que pasaba y de no reaccionar de manera agresiva (Por cuestiones de privacidad no daré más detalles al respecto).

Aprendí del robo de puntos en SOEn, cuando respondí alguna vez inocentemente complementando una respuesta con los pasos que no había dicho y me asignaron la pregunta aceptada a mí. **Es un tema difícil**, porque hacemos todos lo que está a nuestro alcance para ayudar a tantas personas como podamos, y que alguien con mucho tiempo le den la respuesta como aceptada por dedicarle más tiempo **nos puede hacer sentir heridos**, y son famosas ese tipo de quejas en SOEn no por que sean comunes, sino porque la gente cuando se siente herida o decepcionada tiende a ser dramática( razón por la cual me había abstenido de comentar ), y decidí poner memes ( algo de mla gusto ) de algo que normalmente me hace felíz (bien pensado woodie.jpeg).

De alguna manera al ver a alguien con tanta experiencia en el sitio y estar pasando por un mal momento no pude sino sentir que era con toda la mala intención del mundo y que estaba manipulando al usuario y mil y un teorías conspirativas más... Perdón por eso, y gracias por recordarme que **en SOEs siempre debemos de tener y pensar que los demás hacen las cosas con buena fe**.

Si me dolió tanto es porque también me sentí muy acogido en la comunidad cuando ese moderador en particular en ese entonces con el nombre de Elenasys siempre nos motivaba y nos asombraba, sé que el cambio de nombre es un tema personal, pero ese es el tipo de usuario que nos gusta a todos en la comunidad: el que inspira.

Mi recomendación si alguien pasa por esto sería que **no podemos evitar sentirnos decepcionados, pero los moderadores son tan humanos como todos, y este sitio es fuerte gracias a su comunidad**, sin importar lo difícil de la situación, es una **oportunidad de demostrar y si no aprender a mejorar nuestra inteligencia emocional**.

**Si bien los votos no lo son todo en la vida, es una representación del aprecio de la comunidad, de que vale la pena hacer algo por los demás y compartir nuestro valioso conocimiento**, gracias a todos los que me han premiado con su confianza y sus votos, de verdad significan demasiado para mí.

Considero que los **moderadores diamantados** la tienen muy difícil ya que **no pueden permitir ofenderse**, y eso es ago muy difícil, todos llegamos a ponernos difíciles y seguro a ellos les toca batallar con muchos en nuestro momento más difícil.

Un último consejo que no hice porque me dió mucha pena y que debí hacer es **usar el chat si se tiene la suficiente reputación, allí hay un moderador de moderadores**, que para efectos prácticos ayuda a que los problemas no nos afecten tan personalmente y no lleguen a mayores, especialmente si son problemas directamente con los moderadores diamantados.

**Moderadores diamantados, cuiden mucho como los perciben, tiene una gran responsabilidad pues son un símbolo para todos, si sienten que no pueden manejar la situación de la mejor manera pidan ayuda a otro moderador diamantado y háganse a un lado.**

Si se presentan más polémicas no os ofendais, **es una oportunidad para recordarnos quienes somos como personas, como moderadores diamantados o no y como comunidad**.

Gracias a todos por su esfuerzo en este sitio y por dedicar un poco de su tiempo a mis intentos de hacer el stackoverflow en español que todos merecemos.

Comment: Me llegó mucho esta respuesta: como usuario y como exmoderador de otro sitio. Como usuario, porque en SOen muchas veces observé situaciones de este tipo que me crearon enojo y me hicieron que poco a poco fuera absteniéndome de responder para evitar _piques_. La ludificación del sistema, con puntos, medallas y demás, a veces saca cosas raras de la gente. Como exmoderador, porque es un cargo que requiere de intentar ser siempre ecuánime, objetivo y blabla, pero no siempre se tienen las fuerzas.

 Tremenda respuesta, un gran abrazo y a seguir construyendo de forma tan útil como hasta ahora!

Comment: Te honra muchisimo esta respuesta. Reconocer los errores propios (el tono de tu pregunta fue un poco mas allá de la línea en mi opinión, eso es cierto) es el primer paso para llegar a un entendimiento. Todos somos personas y podemos equivocarnos, lo díficil es reconocer el error y pedir disculpas si es necesario. Tu lo has hecho, y yo personalmente como usuario y moderador te lo agradezco enormemente.