# Los moderadores no deberían usar sus poderes de moderador cuando en Meta se pregunta por ellos

Tags: discusión, meta, moderación, moderadores

Vi ayer la pregunta de aquí Meta [El robo de puntos llegó a soes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4937/83) en la que se planteaba una situación de conflicto entre un usuario (el autor de esa pregunta) y un moderador. La verdad es que no acabé de entender demasiado el tono de la publicación, me resultó algo confusa.

En cualquier caso, vi después que el moderador afectado utilizó sus poderes de moderador para (basándose en [la línea de tiempo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/4937/timeline) y el [historial de revisiones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/4937/revisions) de la pregunta):

- eliminarla
- bloquearla
- recuperarla

Tanto la eliminación como el bloqueo fueron simultáneos y hechos por el usuario Comunidad, lo que tiene solo dos posibles causas (en base [a la documentación](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22229/209901)): que seis personas marcaran la publicación como spam o abusiva, o que un moderador lo hizo. Parece que fue lo segundo.

También vi que en la publicación en sí desapareció un comentario y luego volvió a aparecer, algo que solamente un moderador puede hacer. Eso sí, [mi comentario en esa publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/408777/el-contenido-de-un-jtextarea-no-se-guarda-en-un-archivo-y-aun-por-encima-me-da-e/408805#comment733722_408805) puesto al ver la situación sí se mantuvo:

> Creo X que deberías resolver el tema [planteado en Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4937/83) como usuario raso y no utilizar las herramientas de moderador para ello. [Bloquear o eliminar la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/4937/revisions) no ayuda. Mejor pedir a otro moderador que intervenga.

Me resulta preocupante y más porque se trata del mismo moderador que estuvo involucrado en como mínimo [otro incidente](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3900/83) de abuso de las herramientas de moderador.

Creo que es bueno que en Meta se plantee todo y que los moderadores no tienen que temer a la comunidad. Incluso si es para decir que un usuario está equivocado, no es de recibo abusar de sus privilegios y además crea un mal precedente que rompe con la natural confianza que debemos tener con ellos. Además, el decálogo de la moderación dice que todo aquello en lo que estés involucrado *no* debes gestionarlo tú, sino dejarlo a otro moderador (a nivel moderador, se entiende; a nivel usuario sí).

Por ello, creo que es necesario (otra vez) una rectificación y una explicación. Y que no vuelva a pasar.

---

Dicho todo lo cual, espero que no se vea esto como un ataque al moderador en sí. Como he dicho muchas veces, su labor es encomiable y es de gran ayuda a mantener el sitio limpio y útil. Mucho hacen por ser tan pocos (sitios similares suelen tener el doble o el triple de moderadores).

Comment: Se llama "conflicto de intereses". No se puede ser juez y parte.

Comment: Todo StackExchange parte siempre de la confianza, para todo. Los punticos se traducen en confianza, que se manifiesta en lo que puedes ayudar a hacer en el sitio. Si se pierde la confianza, es muy difícil que el resto de la comunidad se sienta cómoda, segura y en confianza. Edito: me queda la duda de si está claro el uso de las herramientas (presumiendo buena fe y mala mano votando o marcando las cosas desde un perfil con superpoderes...)

Comment: Lo que señala Alfabravo es preciso, la confianza es el pilar de SO. Para mi es claramente un abuso de sus poderes(que lo  ha hecho de forma continua) que ya perdio mi confianza. Aunque el otro usuario pudiera tener razón o no, el trabajo del moderador es calmar la situación y no empeorarla.

Comment: @Alfabravo absolutamente de acuerdo. Confianza y transparencia. Solo un moderador puede decirnos qué pasó exactamente, pero no imagino a 6 personas marcando como "abusiva" esa publicación por lo que el reporte de un moderador parece lo realmente plausible. El primer paso sería desbloquear esa otra pregunta y luego aclarar qué pasa.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Yo he revisado(continuamente) esa publicación (antes de que sea bloqueada) para ver la respuesta del moderador y nunca vi un voto de cierre.

Comment: @eyllanesc lo que pasa es que los reportes no aparecen en [la línea de tiempo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/4937/timeline) ni en [las revisiones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/4937/revisions), es algo solo disponible para los moderadores. La única pista es lo de _Publicación eliminada por Comunidad♦_ que explica la eliminación a través de reportes.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' El voto de un moderador diamantado es definitivo por lo que si lo que hubiera cerrado fueran los votos de usuarios *normales* se tomaría su tiempo entre voto y voto por lo que es muy probable que yo lo viera, pero nunca los ví.

Comment: Otro incidente del mismo moderador: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4787/qu%c3%a9-hacer-si-un-moderador-convierte-a-comentario-una-respuesta-v%c3%a1lida

Comment: «Creo que es bueno que en Meta se plantee todo y que **los moderadores no tienen que temer a la comunidad**». Ese fragmento tiene mucho potencial.

Comment: ¿Responderá aclarando la situación?

Comment: @NicolasOñate, supongo que es mejor extraer los enunciados que hacer un juicio que nada arregla ya. Los enunciados (como el que resalté en mi comentario anterior) no tienen nombres, y por eso aplican muy bien a la posteridad y generalidad: sientan un precedente (¡Hay que festejar eso!). Me parece que pedir una comparecencia no ayuda mucho; al menos no más que lo planteado en esta publicación y sus comentarios. Por ejemplo, en los comentarios y publicaciones relacionados (como este), la ética y moral de la comunidad no se daba por sentada, sino que se estaba construyendo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En este caso la publicación que se realizó:

[El robo de puntos llegó a soes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4937/el-robo-de-puntos-lleg%C3%B3-a-soes?cb=1)

Consideré personalmente que los comentarios hacia mi persona:

- "avaricioso usuario"
- "¿Qué deberíamos de hacer en estos casos? ¿Cambiarme mi nombre a "Jorgesys deja de dañar"?"

Eran comentarios que consideré como irrespetuosos.

> "irrespetuoso o abusivo" Una persona razonable consideraría este
> contenido como [inapropiado para un discurso respetuoso](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).

Por tal motivo decidí reportarla bajo este mismo concepto, pero me percaté que **al ser moderador y reportarla se cerraba, e incluso se eliminaba la pregunta instantáneamente**. Es lo que indicas:

> "Tanto la eliminación como el bloqueo fueron simultáneos y hechos por
> el usuario Comunidad"

Realicé la recuperación de la pregunta pero esta quedó bloqueada.

Le pedí a un compañero moderador que me apoyara abriéndola nuevamente.

---

En cuanto a los comentarios que el usuario realizó hacia mí en mi publicación, si también realizo el reporte, se eliminan automáticamente. Si ya no se muestra el comentario que el usuario realizó hacia mí, al final no fue una acción realizada por mí.

---

No veo como ataque lo que preguntas, gracias por tus palabras.

Te comento que he realizado anteriormente reportes de publicaciones, por ejemplo de "Baja calidad",

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero en estos casos la pregunta no se cierra ni se elimina automáticamente, tal vez es la primera ocasión como moderador que reporto una pregunta como "irrespetuoso y abusivo".

Comment: Gracias, Jorge, por tu respuesta, agradezco un montón (y seguro que la comunidad también) este ejercicio de transparencia.

Comment: Es un problema lo de no poder reportar "como usuario normal" cuando eres moderador, pues efectivamente tanto reportar como _contenido no deseado_ e _irrespetuoso o abusivo_ tiene efecto inmediato. Sugiero revisar [dónde se tiene voto de oro](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300783/209901) y consultar en caso de duda, la documentación es muy amplia y hay veces que cuesta saber con exactitud qué reacción tendrá una acción de moderador.