# ¿Cómo limpiamos SOes de preguntas particulares?

Tags: discusión, eliminación-de-preguntas

Hay preguntas, a veces correctamente formuladas, que se refieren a un problema tan extremadamente particular que la respuesta sólo le sirve al OP.

Ejemplo: [Por que estos negative-lookahead no estan logrando restringir un patron regex que decide cuando realizar sustituciones con la funcion re.sub()?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/581744/por-que-estos-negative-lookahead-no-estan-logrando-restringir-un-patron-regex-qu)

Dado que no tienen utilidad para nadie más, la mejor sería eliminarlas luego que el OP haya aceptado la respuesta, pero no veo ningún mecanismo ni causal para hacerlo.

Mantener estas preguntas ensucia los resultados de las búsquedas. Ahora cuando busco algo con "expresiones regulares", obtengo publicaciones sin valor.

¿Cómo limpiamos SOes de preguntas particulares?

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo. En realidad, el proposito de Stack Exchange no es armar una base de datos con preguntas que no sirven a nadie más. Sorprendentemente, no existe el motivo de cierre "esta pregunta no será util para futuros lectores" más allá del motivo de errores tipograficos. Pero supongo que esta propuesta aplica a toda la red y te conviene más hacerla en el meta de SE.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo, aunque ignoro las consecuencias (salvo la de limpiar), por ejemplo, que pasa con los puntos ganados como OP y como "contestador", se que los votos negativos, desparecen cuando se borra una pregunta o respuesta, pero no se los positivos, si es así, muchos se molestarían, por otro lado, se me hace difícil pensar en la "clasificación", casi todas las preguntas sobre fallos (errores de codificación), serían "voladas", y las otras... no sabría decidir, igual tu propuesta tiene mi apoyo, aunque no valga mucho jeje.

Comment: @MarcePuente Estoy de acuerdo con tu comentario, eso de borrar preguntas así nomás podría ser mala idea, hay que hacerlo con cuidado. Solo vengo a aclarar que  tanto positivos como negativos se borran dependiendo de la influencia que ha tenido el usuario. Encontré esto, tiene pinta de ser informativo: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1308/p%C3%A9rdida-de-puntos-por-usuario-eliminado

Comment: Cuando te refieres a "preguntas particulares" estás metiendo en el mismo saco a las preguntas que piden ayuda con la depuración???

Comment: @Yussef. Incluye las preguntas de depuración, las que tienen errores de sintaxis, las que se equivocaron con la sangria, etc. Todo lo que no sea de utilidad para otros.

Comment: estoy de acuerdo pero ese mecanismo traeria mas trabajo a la comunidad ... incluso una cola de visibilidad ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con duplicados.

La mayoría de las veces se puede extrapolar el concepto general que lleva a la respuesta.

Será cuestión de encontrar una pregunta bien formulada que se responda con el mismo concepto (o generar una nueva).

Comment: Es lo que hago, cuando puedo. La dificultad está en encontrar el duplicado entre tanta pregunta anterior.

Comment: @CandidMoe oportun-crisis para crear preguntas con respuestas canónicas que se puedan enlazar?

Comment: @Alfabravo. Ahora las pongo en "favoritas".